# How to install multiple versions of JDK without destroying current settings?

Tags: java, ubuntu, installation, java-5

I'm on an Ubuntu Desktop that is set up with JDK 1.6.34 and everything works great. I'd like to install JDK 1.5.11 in such a way that my environmental variables, etc. don't get "blown out" by the installation of 1.5.11.

Is this even possible? Can the same machine have 2+ JDKs installed on it? If so, what are the necessary steps one needs to take to achieve this?

Comment: Of course, different JDK but it's not always used, so the latest is better and secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can install as many JDK's on a machine as you want.  As for "blowing out" environment variables, this is how you control which jdk you'll use (i.e. make sure the desired jdk's /bin directory is first in the path and that JAVA_HOME points to the JDK you want to be using).

Comment: It might be needed to resort to the binary package from the Java page instead of using the Ubuntu repositories. (I actually prefer to do it that way.)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. (I've been installing my own JDKs for so long I forgot they're in the repo's).  But I think you're right, most package managers won't let you have conflicting versions of packages installed.